# Alternative in using Excel in reporting

Tags: sql, database, excel

Even with the advanced technologies and available database tools (even free alternatives) are available today, it seems that huge number of users are still very comfortable in using Excel IN EVERYTHING! That's why, as a database developer working as one of these users, I am forced to let them use Excel simply because they are very comfortable using it. Especially for the older people who seemed to never gonna let Excel go and embrace a new tool.
Currently, to make their experience as smooth as possible and at the same time, automated, I'm using a lot of database queries inside Excel be it view,SQL or stored procedures. Mostly on ad-hoc (but then became permanent) reports. My question is are there any hopes to improve this situation? I'm sure a lot of organizations are using this same method. Is it possible to completely replace this arrangement with something more logical and efficient both in data collection and reliability? I'm thinking about using Sharepoint. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also struggled with this problem in the past and can say that what worked for me was a two pronged approach.

Step 1 – Make a good alternative

It sounds like you have already done this, depending on the system there will always be some random report that someone needs to run to suit their “Business Need”. There is no way that you could cram all of these into your system as it would fill up with reports and the users would become snow blind.

Step 2 – User education

Show them the new way of making their own reports (Business objects SSRS whatever) and make sure they are comfortable with it. This is the hardest part as some people like their comfort blanket of excel and wont want to leave it. Give them some templates and some standard reports, maybe even pair develop one or two reports at their desk with them so they get the knack of it.

I will leave on a bit of a daily WTF, there was once this expert business manager who was an expert in business objects. She made reports left right and centre but she treated it like a giant version of excel and her work was littered with examples of this i.e. one report she wrote was to get the dealing totals for a year. No problem I hear you cry just do

```
SELECT SUM(DealAmount) where DealDate Between X and Y
```

Nope not our business expert, in here excel frame of mind this was too much like black magic so what she did was return a row for EVERY SINGLE DEAL done in that year and then aggregated it client side to give her a total. In I step and wow the users by reducing this 104mb report that took 17 minutes to run down to a 100kb report that ran in about 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I would go the other way around. And I mean by that, not making queries and database connections within Excel, but using some sort of Web Application to let users (through wizards) generate data they need, and export them to Excel to work.

That way you will have the following benefits:

1. No DB connections (and probably passwords) in your Excel files
2. No distribution problem of Excel files with new queries, views, etc.
3. Centralized approach to data retrieval
4. Excel for users used to it

Comment: Thanks! But I have this setup as well. But then again, after they exported the data on their sheet, they would start messing with it (add charts, formatting, layouts, etc) to make it as their formatted report. Yeah, this is somewhat related to user discipline but I can't stop them all. Thus, the solution I'm currently using and tied the data in another sheet for automatic updating. I know the risks but it seems I have no other choice. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I see... Good point. Maybe, from your Web Application, you can generate an Excel file with DATA UPDATE support through Macros. But using some sort of WebService, not straight connections to the DataBase. It's not straightforward, but definitely a good solution.
Good luck!

Comment: You could always protect the worksheets once the reports have been output, Marco - quite how users would react to that is anyone's guess (OK, it's obvious - they would complain!).

Answer (score 1):

Back in the day, I loved using Crystal Reports for ad-hoc reporting.  I'm not sure about it's current status, as it seems that SAP has purchased the product: http://www.sap.com/solutions/sapbusinessobjects/sap-crystal-solutions/index.epx